# Outer measure in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, with measure $\mu$. Let $A$ be any subset of $X$. We define the *outer measure of $A$* to be the quantity
\begin{equation*}
\mu^*(A) = \inf \{\; \mu(B) \;|\; A \subseteq B, B \in\mathcal{A} \; \}
\end{equation*}

I just want to prove that in fact this infimum is a minimum, that is there exists a set $C \in \mathcal{A}$, $A \subseteq C$, with $\mu(C) = \mu^*(A)$.

By def. there are, for each $n$, subsets $A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ including $A$ such
that
\begin{equation}
\mu(A_n) \leq \mu^*(A) + \frac{1}{n}
\end{equation}

If I can rearrange those $A_n$ in order to get an increasing sequence $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$ then I'm done, the problem is that i have no idea how to construct such a sequence without changing the previous condition in measures.

Comment: Increasing sequence cannot be the correct route. Then (by increasing $n$) $\mu(A_n)$ is supposed to "get smaller" while $A_n$ is supposed to "get larger". Eventually things must go wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Let $B_n\in\mathcal A$ with $A\subseteq B_n$ and $\mu(B_n)\leq\mu^*(A)+\frac1{n}$.

Let $C:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\in\mathcal A$.

Then $A\subseteq C$ so that $\mu^*(A)\leq\mu(C)$ and secondly $C\subseteq B_n$ so that $\mu(C)\leq\mu(B_n)\leq\mu^*(A)+\frac1{n}$.

This for each $n\in\mathbb N$ so that $\mu(C)\leq\mu^*(A)$.

Final conclusion: $C\in\mathcal A$ with $A\subseteq C$ and $\mu(C)=\mu^*(A)$.

Comment: Ok so my error was on thinking about increasing sequences due to unions or some things, and not thinking about intersection instead! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

[I'd try for a decreasing sequence rather than an increasing sequence.]

Observation: If $A\subset A_k$ and $\mu(A_k)\le\mu(A)+1/k$ for $k=1,2$, then $A_2':=A_1\cap A_2$ is in $\mathcal A$, $A\subset A_2'\subset A_1$ and $\mu(A_2')\le\mu(A_2)\le \mu(A)+1/2$. That should give you a start on constructing a decreasing sequence with the properties you require.